# Javascript detect total of multiple select option to be sum up

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a onchange multiple select option that can select multiple course then display the total price in other input values

However how to get the total price if I have another multiple select option for months to be sum up in that input

Each months's price is same

course select option code

```
<select class="form-control" onchange="selectFunction(event)" 
name="pay_course[]" required="" multiple>

<option data-price="1111" value="courseId1">English</option>
<option data-price="2222" value="courseId2">Math</option>
</select>
```

month select option code

```
<select class="form-control" multiple="multiple"  >
        <option selected="selected" value="" name="pay_fee_month[]" disabled="true">Select Month...</option>
        <option value='Janaury'>Janaury</option>
        <option value='February'>February</option>
        <option value='March'>March</option>
        <option value='April'>April</option>
        <option value='May'>May</option>
        <option value='June'>June</option>
        <option value='July'>July</option>
        <option value='August'>August</option>
        <option value='September'>September</option>
        <option value='October'>October</option>
        <option value='November'>November</option>
        <option value='December'>December</option>
    </select>
```

Input to be display the total

```
 <input type="number" value="" id="money" class="form-control">
```

Script

```
 function selectFunction(e) {
 var type_id = $('select option:selected').map(function() {
      return $(this).attr('data-price');
  })
 .get().map(parseFloat).reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b
  });
 console.log(type_id)
 $("#money").val( type_id );
}
```

Comment: Replace `event` by `this` in your `onchange` call, then use `$(this)` in the `selectFunction()` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it another way... Completely.

What you wish to have is the total price based on selected courses multiplied by the amount of selected months.

Below, is a script that does just that... On `change` of both selects.

```js
$("#courses, #months").on("change", function(){
  
  // Get the total price of the selected courses.
  var price = 0;
  $("#courses").find("option:selected").each(function(){
    price += $(this).data("price");
  });
  console.log(price);
  
  // Get the amount of selected months.
  var monthCount = $("#months").find("option:selected").length;
  console.log(monthCount);
  
  // Multiply.
  var total = monthCount * price;
  $("#money").val(total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="form-control" id="courses" name="pay_course[]" required="" multiple>

  <option data-price="1111" value="courseId1">English</option>
  <option data-price="2222" value="courseId2">Math</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control" id="months" multiple="multiple"  >
  <option value="" name="pay_fee_month[]" disabled>Select Month...</option>
  <option value='January'>January</option>
  <option value='February'>February</option>
  <option value='March'>March</option>
  <option value='April'>April</option>
  <option value='May'>May</option>
  <option value='June'>June</option>
  <option value='July'>July</option>
  <option value='August'>August</option>
  <option value='September'>September</option>
  <option value='October'>October</option>
  <option value='November'>November</option>
  <option value='December'>December</option>
</select>

 <input type="number" value="" id="money" class="form-control">
```

Notice that I removed the inline `onchange` handler and used jQuery [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

I also removed the `selected="selected"` on the first month option since it also is disabled.